# JS file not working CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

So yeah here I am after searching for quite sometime, I said myself that it's time to post instead...

I've got CodeIgniter on my localhost and I am using WAMP server.

I have put this in **constants.php**

```
define('URL','http://localhost/ci/');
define('IMG',URL.'assets/images/');
define('CSS',URL.'assets/css/');
define('JS',URL.'assets/js/');
```

Then, I put it in my view **site_header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="<?php echo(JS.'custom.js'); ?>"></script>
```

and on the page source the ouput HTML syntax is correct,

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://localhost/ci/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

also, when I go the the link it displays the inside of the js file,

```
alert('Hello, this should work!');
```

BUT, unfortunately, I am not receiving the alert. I am really new to CodeIgniter, I just installed it few days ago, and It would really be helpful if anyone could answer me.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: @Unlockedluca so you wanted me to remove `type="text/javascript"`, DONE, but still its not working..

Comment: for a script its not href.. its src.. just read that chapter at w3schools, I think you will be fine after that

Comment: Use <script src=""> instead of href

Comment: oh my God, how stupid of me to forgot the most basic of all. thaanks..

Answer (score 1):

should edit `href` to `src`

`<script href="<?php echo(JS.'custom.js'); ?>"></script>`

into

`<script src="<?php echo(JS.'custom.js'); ?>"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put like this `<script src="<?php echo(URL.JS.'custom.js'); ?>"></script>`

Comment: @Shaftqat Jan this is wrong because `URL = http://localhost/ci/` and `JS = URL.'assets/js/'` so that makes it, `http://localhost/ci/http://localhost/ci/assets/js`...